# Como colocar três pontos em uma palavra se o texto transbordar a página?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, ux

Gostaria de saber como colocar três pontos na última palavra que  excede o limite da página.

Essa imagem é como está o texto atual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E essa imagem é como eu quero que fique com os três pontos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está o arquivo inteiro do site https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vv3hm7mtg348ot4/AABAVbKixOZEIZi2C_hvaEdfa?dl=0

HTML: pastebin.com/JfaRDHih

CSS: pastebin.com/KhNRiier

Eu tenho medo que os usuários de mobile não percebam que tem mais texto para baixo por isso quero acrescentar esses três pontos.

aqui está o site também se quiserem testar nos seus celulares http://ticianatc.esy.es/VerticalShowcaseSlider/

Comment: Não tenho conta no dropbox e o dropbox não deixa baixar os arquivos sem estar logado. Você não conseguiria copiar os arquivos pertinentes aqui caso você considere a minha resposta insuficiente?

Comment: Opa blz vou editar o post

Comment: Aqui está o HTML: http://pastebin.com/JfaRDHih e Aqui o CSS: http://pastebin.com/KhNRiier

Comment: A sua pergunta é essencialmente de implementação: você quer saber como construir as reticências, e não se essa é a melhor abordagem. Logo, a resposta que você já tem me parece ótima. Ainda assim, você usou a tag [tag:UX]. Logo, eu vou dar uma opinião: essa *não me parece* a melhor abordagem. O padrão de quase todos os sistemas operacionais móveis também é de usar uma área de rolagem (ou um indicador de rolagem), como as barrinhas laterais na direita [dessa imagem](http://assets.sbnation.com/assets/1242058/ios_android_scrollbar_comparison_560.jpg), por exemplo.

Comment: Sendo assim, por que você não segue o que é convencionado e aproveita o que os usuários já sabem sobre como usar sistemas móveis? Além disso, [reticências](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retic%C3%AAncias) em texto podem indicar também figuras de linguagem. Elas também indicam pensamento, omissão ou mesmo uma ideia que ficou por terminar (e que ficaria a cargo do leitor interpretar, por exemplo). Não é exatamente o caso desse exemplo, em que o texto fica bastante sem sentido sem o restante, mas dependendo do texto ainda pode ocorrer de o usuário não entender que há mais conteúdo...

Comment: Sim é verdade Luiz, porém o que me intriga é que não aparece essa barra de rolagem para o usuário pelo menos no meu celular. E eu fico preocupado se alguns não terão a noção de que tem mais texto para baixo. Só gostaria de uma forma de criar  essas reticências e que elas desaparecessem ao rolar o texto para baixo.

Comment: Mas é só por curiosidade mesmo, não utilizarei no site que estou criando

Comment: "[...] o que me intriga é que não aparece essa barra de rolagem para o usuário pelo menos no meu celular." Bom, então o problema é outro. Vc devia ter perguntado por que a barra não aparece.

Answer (score 3):

Acrescente as seguintes propriedades CSS à sua div:

```css
.sua-div {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```